# Dynamic is significantly faster and more responsive with LinkSnooper

Tags: dynamic, gui-construction

I noticed an absolutely bizarre behavior of `Dynamic`. A simple dynamic module with `SynchronousUpdating -> False` is significantly *more* responsive with LinkSnooper than using the Local kernel. I did not modify either of the evaluator configurations. Is this a known, er, feature?

I am using the function `Gamma` below only to make sure that evaluation will happen in the kernel. Being asynchronous, it most probably will anyway, but I just wanted to be completely sure.

```
In[1]:= {$System, $VersionNumber}

Out[1]= {"Microsoft Windows (64-bit)", 11.3}

In[2]:= DynamicModule[{x},
 Column[{
   Options[EvaluationNotebook[], Evaluator],
   Slider[Dynamic[x]],
   Dynamic[Gamma[x + 1], SynchronousUpdating -> False]}]
 ]

(* {Evaluator -> "Local"}, a slider, 1. *)
```

Dragging the slider causes a noticeable delay, and the window menu flickers like crazy.

```
In[32]:= SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], Evaluator -> "LinkSnooper"]

In[33]:= (* Same Dynamic module as above *)

(* {Evaluator -> "LinkSnooper"}, a slider, 1. *)
```

I would not call this slider *extremely smooth*, but it is noticeably smoother than the first. Scrolling log in LinkSnooper just flies non-stop, and I would expect this would slow the frontent-to-kernel communication... but this makes it actually faster! What is going on?

I tried:

- Verifying the kernel options are same in the running kernel process command line.
- Running the text mode kernel `math` instead of the default `WolframLanguageKernel`.
- Restarting the whole rig before each test. Same result.
- Doing other stupid things with the command line. Most of them broke it, other had no effect. For one, removing `-wstp` and adding `-noinit` definitely did not do anything, but I have no idea what I was doing.

I am running out of ideas. Has anyone seen that?

Here is a demonstration of the effect:

[image]

Comment: I've inlined your recording into the question body. For the future, simply upload the recording as a GIF like you would upload an image (i.e. the button or CTRL+G). To get the GIF, either record directly to a GIF (I use [ScreenToGif](https://www.screentogif.com), but there are many others), or simply convert the MP4 or whatever to one, which is what I did here. For that, just google "MP4 to GIF online" and you'll get plenty of options.

Comment: @LukasLang: Thank you so much! I though about a multiframe GIF, but mp4 is usually so much more compact, so I did not even try it. Wrong \$Assumptions, entirely my bad! :)

Comment: I do observe this effect with version 11.3, but not with version 12.0.0 where the slider is equally responsible in the both cases (OS Windows 7 x64).

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov, thanks for the heads-up! I have not upgraded yet, but it looks I should.